# Migration from "com.auth0.jwt.JWT" to "io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts"

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jwt

I create tokens with com.auth0.jwt.JWT. My code works perfect on Android version 26 and higher.

```
JWT.create().apply {
    withExpiresAt(Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + time))
    withClaim("myClaim" claim)
    ...     
}.sign(Algorithm.HMAC256("my secret key")
```

But I need to use it on an Android version below 26.
When I do it I get the exception

> "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.auth0.jwt.JWTCreator"`

I heard about the library io.jsonwebtoken.jwts. I decided to try, but did not find any methods by which I could use my secret key.

Answer (score 0):

Example of how to generate a token in Java using **io.jsonwebtoken**

```
public static final String SECRET = "5367566B59703373367639792F423F4528482B4D6251655468576D5A71347437";

    public String generateToken(String email) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .header()
                .keyId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .and()
                .subject(email)
                .issuedAt(new Date())
                .expiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 30))
                .signWith(getSignKey())
                .compact();
    }

    private SecretKey getSignKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(SECRET.getBytes());
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }
```

Comment: *.expiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 30))*  - JWT uses UNIX timestamps in seconds, not in milliseconds.

Comment: It works. But with android 24 I got exception. 
`io.jsonwebtoken.io.SerializationException: Cannot serialize JWS Protected Header to JSON. Cause: Unable to serialize object of type io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwsHeader: No virtual method getParameterCount()I in class Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.Constructor' appears in /system/framework/core-oj.jar`

Comment: I am not very familiar with Android, but did you imported all required libraries?

Like `implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.12.3'`

Comment: I use `"io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.12.3"` , `"io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.12.3"` and `"io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.12.3"`. Perhaps I should add something else.